# Returning view in ASP.Net Core via jQuery AJAX - Not working in production

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am returning a view from a controller and using jquery to display the result. It works perfectly in debug but when I publish it to the server once the ajax result is returned(and is correct) It blanked out all elements. Its driving me mad! I thought it may be a timeout issue but obviously not as I tried it up to 200 milliseconds.

JS:

```
    function openRestaurantList() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/restaurants",
            success: function (result) {
                document.title = "Restaurants";
                $("body").html(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [Route("restaurants")]
    public IActionResult Restaurants()
    {
        ViewBag.Data = Place.FetchFullListByType(Place.Types.Restaurant);
        return View("RestaurantList");
    }
```

[image: Before Ajax call]

[image: After Ajax]

Comment: Is `result` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yup, it returning me what I want. There are no errors in the network.

Comment: No way to help without being able to see what is actually in `body` after the ajax and inspect css in browser dev tools inspector

Comment: `console.log(result)` to double-check.  Check that you're not loading through a proxy that's making dubious changes to either the first page or the ajax result.

Comment: Added photos, not sure if it will help, I did a console.log and the result is absolutely fine. Its just all the elements are gone.

Comment: Try `.empty().html( string )`. Is there any mini-demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URL that you are using is relative to the path you are in.

Replace “/restaurants” for “@Url.Action(“restaurants”, “controllerName”)” that will give you the absolute url to the action.

You can also inspect the page (F12 in chrome) and look at the network tab, you will see a 404 error about the restaurants action. There you can get information about what URL are you hitting with the jquery call.

Comment: This is not the issue, it is getting to the controller and returning the correct result. Issue has to be on the client side.

Comment: Add a div inside the body and put the html on that doc. Changing body html is not recommended.

Comment: Gave that a go and its still blanking everything out.

Comment: your Action should return a partialview instead a view. As in the case of the view you are returning a whole page with html tag. It will not work.